# Struct - Explain the output:

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

I have the following C code.

```
struct values{
  int a:3;
  int b:3;
  int c:2;
};

void main(){
  struct values v={2,-6,5};
  printf("%d %d %d",v.a,v.b,v.c); 
}
```

When I execute the code, I am getting the following output:

```
2 2 1.
```

But output should be `2 -6 5`, right?

If I'm wrong please explain.

Comment: Are you familiar with the bit fields? (:3 etc)

Comment: The Clang compiler on OS X gives me a nice warning: *"implicit truncation from 'int' to bitfield changes value from -6 to 2 [-Wconstant-conversion]"*.

Answer (score 5):

`-6` exceeds the range of a 3-bit signed int.  Therefore you're observing an artifact of <s>undefined</s> implementation-defined behaviour (in practice, the most-significant bits of your value are being thrown away).

Comment: yes but implementation defined behavior (c99, 6.3.1.3p3) not undefined

Answer (score 4):

```
{2,             |  -6,             |        5        }
010 last 3 bits |  010 last 3 bits |  01 last 2 bits
2                  2                        1
```

Comment: Consider elaborating a little on this answer.

Comment: @P0W  Was simply looking through the answers and was in no mood to vote but could not resist after looking at your explanation ..... brief but explains everything except if one understands something .. +1 :) and for others too :P

Answer (score 1):

No. Output is `2 2 1`.

The C compiler converts the values to Binary, and stores in the memory.

Binary value of 2  : `00000010`

Binary value of -6: `11111010` (11111001+1)

Binary value of 5 : `00000101`

While storing in memory:

For 2, 010 will be stored.

For -6, 010 will be stored.

For 5, 01 will be stored.

When you access these variables from your main method, for v.a "010" will be returned, here left most bit is for sign.

So v.a is 2. Similarly v.b is 2 and v.c is 1.

Hope it helps.